# Manually update angular template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable `$scope.liking`. It get's updated whenever somone clicks a like-button, that triggers the listener `FB.Event.subscribe`.

```
controller('LikeCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
  var page_like_callback = function(url, html_element) {
    $scope.liking = true;
    console.log($scope);
  };

  console.log($scope);
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', page_like_callback);
}]);
```

In my template i have a 
`<p>{{liking}}</p>`

It won't update when `FB.Event.subscribe` fires. I can see with `console.log` that the scope is updated. Can I kick it to make the template upload or change the code somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback is executed outside of the control of Angular. You need to explicitly evaluate the expression in the context of `$scope`. You can do so with [`$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24apply):

```
var page_like_callback = function(url, html_element) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.liking = true;
    });
};
```